# SELECT * plus all rows that are associated with the IDs of another column of the same table

Tags: mysql, select

I have one table: `user_relationship`. I'm needing to select all rows of a `employee_id` as well as all the other rows that contain those `client_id`(s).

```
id | employee_id | client_id
1  | 365         | 12
2  | 874         | 63
3  | 365         | 48
4  | 471         | 12
5  | 471         | 48
6  | 522         | 90

SELECT * FROM `user_relationship` WHERE `employee_id` = 471

id | employee_id | client_id
4  | 471         | 12
5  | 471         | 48
```

But am needing to add to that query so that it then also selects all `employee_id` associated with the returned `client_id`(s):

```
id | employee_id | client_id
1  | 365         | 12
3  | 365         | 48
4  | 471         | 12
5  | 471         | 48
```

Could I please get some help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a subquery. This should work.

```
SELECT * FROM `user_relationship` WHERE `client_id` IN (SELECT `client_id` FROM `user_relationship` WHERE `employee_id` = 471)
```

Here's the documentation on the topic https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Comment: Ah! subquery was the keyword I needed. Works like a charm, thanks!